# Rails ActiveRecord::Relation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Looking into passing a variable as value on ActiveRcord query key/column?

```
login = Login.where("email_address" => "geo@bostj.com","active" => 1).select("id")
=> [#<Login id: 767>]
login = Login.where("email_address" => "geo@bostj.com","active" => 1).select("id").class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation

admin = Admin.where("login_id"=>login).exists?
```

Heeeelp

Answer (score 2):

You can write as

```
login_ids = Login.where("email_address" => "geo@bostj.com","active" => 1).pluck(:id)
Admin.where("login_id in (?)", login_ids).blank?
```

[`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-blank-3F)

> Returns true if relation is blank.

`Admin.where("login_id in (?)", login_ids)` gives back us `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, so I think we can use `#blank?` method.

Comment: `blank?` method will firstly load all the records and perform array's `blank?` on the target array - it will not limit query so it might have an impact on performance.

Comment: @BroiSatse It is not a `Array#blank?`... `ActiveRecord::Relation#blank?` .. In my console I can  see only one query - `2.1.0 :014 > User.where(:id => 7).blank?
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 7
D, [2014-05-30T17:47:46.636800 #8519] DEBUG -- :   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 7
 => false`

Comment: If you look into the source of this method, it is just `to_a.blank?`. Also note that there is no `LIMIT` on the query, which can make it much longer for a large number of records.

Comment: @BroiSatse Regarding `limit` method, *interesting*. But OP didn't mention about this. OP is checking is the mentioned credentials are exist in `log_in` table. If so, then check if it is `Admin` or not. I don't know, how *limit* is needed here. But yes OP knows about this more than me, what his/her need is about *limit*. But thanks for your comments. if the *association* OP tells us, I could write it in some other way also. But as OP didn't mention, so I didn't work on this.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
login = Login.where(email_address: 'geo@bostj.com', active: 1)
Admin.exists?(login_id: login.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: Or simply `Admin.exists?(login_id: login)`, recent versions of Rails optimize such queries.

Comment: @Stefan - That would be pretty nice, however I find it quite hard to read and understand. Also according to code, it will perform map on relation array, which means it will first create all AR models, which is not necessary here.

Comment: Rails 4 would use a sub query, something like `SELECT 1 AS one FROM admins WHERE admins.login_id IN (SELECT logins.id FROM logins WHERE logins.email_address = 'geo@bostj.com' AND logins.active = 1) LIMIT 1`, without instantiating any AR model

Comment: @Stefan - That is awesome. I thought it will just call `to_param` on relation. Need to look a little more. Thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
admin = Admin.where("login_id" => login.first.id).exists?
```