# Ruby if statement multiline condition syntax?

Tags: ruby

Hi all new to ruby is this if statement valid syntax?

```
if (verify_login_id = Login.where(params[:email_address], "active" =>1).select('id')# => [#<Login id: 767>]  
verify_admin_id = Admin.where("login_id" => verify_login_id.first.id).exists? #=> true) 
puts "trueee"
else
raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new("Authorization is required to access this endpoint!"))
end
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? As it stands the code is not valid, and it allows several interpretations about your aims.

Comment: Can you explain what the code is supposed to do, please?

Comment: I told you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951490/rails-activerecordrelation-error/23951683#23951683) . Then why are you making it so complex. Don't put such long statement inside the `if` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Although setting variable values within an `if` statement is syntactically valid, it is very problematic.

It can be mistakenly read as a comparison rather than assignment, and in many cases it is a result of someone trying to make a comparison and confusing the equals predicate `==` with the assignment operator `=`. That's why a lot of IDEs today mark such code as a warning and a probable error.

In your code it also seems quite unneeded... Break it into two more readable lines:

```
verified_login = Login.where(params[:email_address], "active" =>1).select('id').first # => [#<Login id: 767>]  

if verified_login && Admin.where("login_id" => verified_login.id).exists? #=> true
  puts "trueee"
else
  raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new("Authorization is required to access this endpoint!"))
end
```

Some more observations - your assignment to `verify_login_id` is not an id, but a `Login` object, and your assignment to `verify_admin_id` is not an id either - but a boolean (and you are not using it anyway). This might seem besides the point - but it adds up to an unreadable and an unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a valid code. In the second line, it contains an invalid #-comment that has removed a single `)` from the code. (exact snip is `#=>true)` and should be `) #=>true`)

I've removed the comments from the code, added the missing parenthesis and the parser seems to accept it. I couldn't run it of course. So, try this one, it *might* work:

```
if (verify_login_id = Login.where(params[:email_address], "active" =>1).select('id')
  verify_admin_id = Admin.where("login_id" => verify_login_id.first.id).exists?)
  puts "trueee"
else
  raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new("Authorization is required to access this endpoint!"))
end
```

Regarding multiline condition in the `if` - yes, it is possible. Sometimes directly, sometimes with a small trick. Try this:

```
if (1+2 >= 
    3)
  puts "as"
end
```

It works (at least on Ruby 1.9.3). However, this will not:

```
if (1+2
    >= 
    3)
  puts "as"
end
```

This is because of some internal specific of how Ruby interpreter/compiler is designed. In the last example, to make it work, you need to inform Ruby that the line **has not ended**. The following example works:

```
if (1+2 \
    >= 
    3)
  puts "as"
end
```

Note the `\` added at the end of problematic line

Comment: Why inside the `if` clause, such a big statement you are adjusting ?

Comment: Because this was the question. I have found a possible cause, so I answer. The code is crappy, but the question is not about it. It's about syntax and a parsing problem.

Comment: If someone ask you bad question, you don't need to answer that way. You can suggest him some good approaches too.

Comment: If someone asks me bad question,I respond to that question because it was asked. If the person **does not know** then the person is usually unable to ask a proper, well defined question. It is a part of learning process. Answering to the bad question allows them to understand their failure better and learn quicker and on wider subjects.If my kid asks how to build a mechanical flying elephant, I wouldn't explain that it's silly and make him build paper planes. I'd explain the thing briefly, and then try to understand what he wants more: flying, elephant or mechnical and pursue that or all those